# How to use a thenable with a computed property in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What is the correct way to use a thenable as one of the dependent keys of a computed property in Ember in 2018?

I would like the computed property to update when the promise/thenable resolves without jumping through hoops. I do this:

```
payableId: computed('paymentRecord.isSettled', function() {
  let paymentRecord = this.get('paymentRecord');
  if (paymentRecord.get('isSettled') === false) return;
  if (paymentRecord.content) paymentRecord = paymentRecord.content;

  return paymentRecord.belongsTo('payable').id();
}),
```

In my example, I have a `paymentRecord` which belongs to a `payable` and I want to get some information about the `payable` but the `paymentRecord` is not resolved until some unknown point in the future. The `paymentRecord` may or may not be a thenable so we have to jump through various hoops:

- Have to be careful to check `isSettled` against `false` since `undefined` would indicate not a thenable
- Have to drill down into `.content` if it exists in the case of a thenable

But it feels like a hack and I can't find anything about this in the guides.

Edit:

`paymentRecord` is an ember data model with `belongsTo` `payable`, another ember data model. My goal is to read the ID of `payable` without triggering a request.

Comment: as i understand you want to execute/get `payableId` if `paymentRecord.isSettled` change ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. My solution works but it's ugly especially since I have to do `.content`.

Comment: maybe split into 2 computed properties - payable and payableID. `payable` returns `this.get('paymentRecord')`  and `payableId` returns `this.get('payable').belongsTo( 'payable').id()`

Comment: What would be the dependent key for the one that returns `this.get('paymentRecord')`? I thought the keys have to be primitives.

Comment: Is payment record an ember data model? In that case it should be a PromiseObject and `reads('paymentRecord.payable.id')` should be fine.

Comment: @jelhan yes its an ember data model. But I'm trying to avoid triggering a request. `paymentRecord.payable` might send a request if its not in the store already. I'm doing the `paymentRecord.belongsTo('payable').id()` dance to avoid a request.

Comment: Got it. Could you please set up an Ember Twiddle demonstrating your issue? I didn't got yet why you need `.content`. In a first guess I think something like `computed('paymentRecord.payable.id', function() { return this.get('paymentRecord.isLoaded') ? this.get('paymentRecord').belongsTo('payable').id() : undefined; })` should work. Dependent keys should not trigger a request. `paymentRecord.isLoaded` guards against calling `belongsTo()` on a pending record, which may not be needed at all if `paymentRecord` is a PromiseObject but didn't investigated that one in detail.